Streaming logs throws "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" error. How to deal with that?
I have a Python app that's streaming logs to a third-party service (in this case, it's an AWS S3 bucket).
My simplified code looks like this:
class S3Handler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, bucket_name, key):
        super().__init__()
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.key = key
        self.s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
            endpoint_url=...,
            aws_access_key_id=...,
            aws_secret_access_key=...)

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            log_entry = self.format(record).encode('utf-8')
            self.s3_client.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=self.key, Body=log_entry, ACL="public-read")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while logging to S3: {str(e)}")

s3_handler = S3Handler(bucket_name='mybucketname', key='path/to/logfile.txt')
logging.getLogger().addHandler(s3_handler)

The goal is that when I run my script, all logs would be saved in the S3 bucket. The script can run for 30 seconds or it can run for 10 hours.
When I run this code, I get immediately this error:
Error while logging to S3: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

After some googling, I found out that the reason behind this error is exceeding the default quota of 1000 iterations that Python provides. There's a way to increase this quota, but I don't find it practical, or feasible for this particular case.
Apparently, my approach to streamline the script's logs to an S3 bucket is not ideal. What are the options to resolve this problem?

I know this is a placeholder in the question, but I think the value for key in the code S3Handler(... key='path/to/logfile.txt') should be a keyfile and not a logfile. Just to make sure..

Also: I am not sure that using print inside a logger is safe, I don't know if that could cause the recursion problem

Are you able to get the error stacktrace, to see which line causes the recursion?

The problem with your code is how it handles each log message. Here's why the recursion error occurs and alternative solutions:
Understanding the Recursion Error:

Your S3Handler.emit function formats the log record and encodes it as UTF-8.
This creates a new string object.
Inside the try block, if there's an error uploading the log, the print statement attempts to format the error message (which might contain the original log record).
This triggers formatting of the original log record again, leading to a loop and exceeding the recursion limit.

Solutions:
Here are a few ways to address this issue:

Log Errors Separately:

Instead of printing the error message within the emit function, log it to a separate logger or standard error stream. This prevents the recursive loop:
def emit(self, record):
    try:
        # ... your existing code for uploading logs ...
    Except Exception as e:
        # Log the error to a separate logger or standard error
        error_logger = logging.getLogger('error_logger')
        error_logger.error(f"Error logging to S3: {str(e)}")


Buffer Logs and Upload Periodically:

Instead of uploading each log message individually, accumulate them in a buffer and upload them periodically to S3. This reduces the number of API calls and avoids recursion:
class BufferedS3Handler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, bucket_name, key, buffer_size=10):
        super().__init__()
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.key = key
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size
        self.buffer = []
        self.s3_client = boto3.client('s3', ...)

    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record).encode('utf-8')
        self.buffer.append(log_entry)
        if len(self.buffer) >= self.buffer_size:
            self.flush_buffer()

    def flush_buffer(self):
        if self.buffer:
            # Upload the entire buffer content to S3 using put_object
            all_logs = b'\n'.join(self.buffer)
            self.s3_client.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=self.key, Body=all_logs)
            self.buffer.clear()


Use a Third-Party Library:

Several libraries like aws-logging-handlers can simplify S3 logging. These libraries handle buffering, retries, and other functionalities:
from aws_logging_handlers.s3 import S3Handler

s3_handler = S3Handler(bucket="mybucketname", key="path/to/logfile.txt")
logging.getLogger().addHandler(s3_handler)

Choosing the Right Solution:

Option 1 is simple but might not be efficient for high-volume logs.
Option 2 offers a balance between performance and complexity.
Option 3 is the easiest to implement but adds an external dependency.

When selecting the best approach, consider your application's log volume and desired complexity.
Update: a real-world test with FastAPI + Uvicorn

Used a local text file instead of s3 to see how it goes
Ran the fastapi app using uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
Everything works fine with buffer_size being 3

# app.py
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

from handler import TextFileLogHandler

app = FastAPI()

log_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
log_handler = TextFileLogHandler(
    file_name="/path/to/logs.txt",
    buffer_size=3
)
log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(log_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


@app.get("/")
async def home():
    logger.info("Heartbeat is ..OK")
    return JSONResponse({"status": "OK", "message": "Pong"})

# handler.py
import logging


class TextFileLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, file_name, buffer_size=10):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size
        self.buffer = []

    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record).encode('utf-8')
        self.buffer.append(log_entry)

        if len(self.buffer) >= self.buffer_size:
            self.flush_buffer()

    def flush_buffer(self):
        if self.buffer:
            all_logs = b'\n'.join(self.buffer)
            with open(self.file_name, "ba") as f:
                f.write(all_logs)
            self.buffer.clear()


@RihanK thank you for your reply. I am playing with the option #2 and I observe that if I set that batch size below 100, then the log file is not created in the bucket. When I set values like 100, 200 or 500, the file gets created. Why is that? In the end of my script, I manually call flush_buffer() function to ensure that  regardless of the size of the log, it always should be uploaded to S3, but for some reason it's not the case. Am I overlooking something?

That's weird! I don't see any issue with batch size being lower. Please double-check your connection and all. Otherwise, it seems ok to me.

Also, I suspect that there must be somewhere in the code called flush_buffer to end the recruision?

Hmmm. I will play around with it and get back.

Thanks - also, I am wondering, cannot be there a problem with a few loggers battling each other?

I performed a real-world test with text-based logging. Please check the updated answer and let me know if it was helpful at all. Thanks
